# Error in activating Publishing feature in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing

I am receiving an error message saying "**A duplicate content type name "Display Template" was found.**" when trying to activate publishing feature at SharePoint online site collection.

this site collection was initially created as a team site.

pls share your thoughts.

Comment: check this https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/288361

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE :  it says you need to delete and recreate which i dont want since it has lots of content. i posted an answer via powershell which what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SharePoint online Management Shell to activate the feature.

To identify the exact feature ID, we need to browse the manage site features ro site collection feature page and inspect the specific feature button in browser developer tools using F12 and grab the unique GUID.

use that in the powershell with example as shown below:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell
$siteurl="https://sitecollectionurl.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite"

[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteurl)   

$username="loginname@domain.com"
$secure_string_pwd = convertto-securestring "yourpassword" -asplaintext -force

$clientContext.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $secure_string_pwd)


$site = $clientContext.Site;    
$featureguid = new-object System.Guid "f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa"     
$site.Features.Add($featureguid, $true, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None);     
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

[Reference blog for more details](http://www.kbasrai.com/b/2013/10/08/managing-features-in-office-365-via-powershell)

Comment: What difference does it make when activating through UI or Management shell?